# Rendering HTML stored in Database Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm storing some HTML in my sqlite database. I'm trying to render this in a web page. However, it renders the tags in the page and I don't want this to be the case.

views.py:

```
textBody = textBody.query.filter_by(id=TextId).first()
data = {
'textToBeRendered': textBody.htmlTextBody
}
return render('home.html', data = data)
```

home.html:

```
<div class = "content">
<p id = "textBody" class = "formatted-text">
{{ data.textToBeRender }}
</p>
</div>
```

text to be rendered is:

```
 <div>
      Hello there, this is <b> Important </b>. Don't forget your appointment at 12pm today. 

      <u> Address </u> <br/>
      123 Street <br/>
      city<br/>
      code 
      <br/><br/>
      <u> Notes </u> <br/>
      <span class = "important">Don't forget to bring the presentation with you! </span> 
      <br>
 </div>
```

At the moment when I pull this information through into home.html it renders the raw text and I actually want it to render the html tags.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple, add `safe` in template:

```
{{ data.textToBeRender | safe }}
```